# why font-weight is not working on some elements, and side questions

Tags: javascript, css

the page in question:
[t.whstonecabinet.com](http://t.whstonecabinet.com)

The element in question is the the module title "Counter Top" Under the slideshow image, I want this title to be thicker. From the developer tools, I can see the font-weight style is governed by a delcaration `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:normal}`, so I tried to add `font-weight:bold` into element.style. But it seems nothing changes to the title.

I also check it with javascript:

```
$('h2.title>div')[0].style.fontWeight
```

returns `''`, so I do

```
$('h2.title>div')[0].style.fontWeight='bold'
```

It turns out this is equivalent to directly write the style into element.style. So I'm stuck here, why font-weight:bold won't affect this element?

Besides, when I use javascript to check this element's fontWeight property, it returns a empty string. I understand that indicates the style isn't set explicitly, but how can I get a computed style of an element using javascript even it is not set?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us your html ?

Comment: I found the answer for my first question, see the answer. But I need answer for my 2nd question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-family: 'Walkway', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`  does not support `font-weight`
and for computed style you can use take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) and yes works above IE9
to use it works like this

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.body, null)
alert(computedStyle.<the property>)
```

Comment: Thank you. I read this before but forgot, 30 secs after I post the question I recalled it..

Comment: haha yup, saw your answer after. Also take a look at 'getComputedStyle' for property. I updated the answer for that too

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at a follow-up problem. If I set the font-family to "foo", then `window.getComputedStyle(myele.fontFamily)` would return "foo" too, but apprently the actual font-family should be some some default font-family, because 'foo' font doesn't exist. So in this case it isn't actually getting "computed style", any other way to get the actual font-family?

Comment: I see what you mean. But if you set the font-family to 'foo' and use Chrome Dev tools to check the font-family its set to foo.. so the function is returning the correct value. But what really happens is. depending on the browser/OS, if the family is not found it sets a default family.. now the question will be how to get the default browser font-family. not sure how to get it dynamically but here is a list to get started [link](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/)

Comment: exactly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out why the `font-weight:bold` is not working.
Font-weight:bold is only effective to some certain fonts, in this case the font is 'walkway', I think it doesn't have a bold fontface.

I still need answer for my second question though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question... `object.style` contains styles applied directly to the element. CSS styles applied using selectors like tagName, className, or id will not show up in `object.style`.

This is the native JavaScript you're looking for:

```
getComputedStyle(element).propertyName
```

Also, there is [jQuery's .css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
$(selector).css(propertyName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `window.getComputedStyle` solves my second question.

Comment: i think you're meaning to add this a comment, not an answer

Comment: This is an answer to my 2nd question.